# opacity in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the opacity black ( if possible )

My jQuery is:

```
jQuery('#list a[rel^="myPhoto"]').my422PortfolioThumbsHover({
    defaultOpacity: 1,
    onMouseOverOpacity: 0.6,
    speed: 300,
    zoomImg: 'zoom.png'
});
```

I tried adding:

background-color: #000000, into the above code... but doesnt wanna play.

Also thought hmm, perhaps I need to wrap the hex color in ' and ' but again zilch ...

Then wondered if I am just going MAD lol

As it is it whitens opacity on hover to 60% , I need that opacity to be 60% but blackened not whitened.

Comment: Opacity modifies transparency.  0 is full transparent and 1 is fully opaque (not transparent).

Comment: I know what opacity is and the values, just didnt know if could be done within js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cover your element with another and fade that new element from transparent into black. You could cover the element by adding the new element to the same parent and absolutely positioning it over the photo.

Comment: Yeah I kinda figured I would need a intermediate div. Have fixed now using trusty css: background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #010101 !important;
 opacity:0.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50);

Answer (score 1):

Opacity isn't a color. It's the opacity of the object you are applying it too. If you want something to fade from black to nothing, then you need to make an element that is black, and then set the opacity of that.